# Remove user permission for specific folder

Tags: permissions, chmod, chown

I have created folder in home. I have also created new user.

I want that specific folder can only be accessed by the new created user. I want to remove root privileges for that folder.

I am using this command to give ownership to that user

```
chown -R newUser:newUser folder_name
```

It is changing the ownership to new user but it is still accessible by other users. I want that it can only be accessed by new user and root and not by the previously created users.

Comment: define "root permission". If you refer that root can access, root can access everything, even if set to 000 permissions.

Answer (score 5):

You can't revoke access permissions from root. It's special user that by design should access almost everything.